# Creating a Stored Procedure to Select from table and Insert line into log table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble creating a Stored Procedure that allows the user to select from a table (medicoes) and inserts a line into log_medicoes for audit purposes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_medicoes ()

RESULT (ID_variavel INTEGER, Num_medicao INTEGER, ID_cultura INTEGER, Data_hora DATE, Valor INTEGER)

BEGIN
DECLARE ID_novo INTEGER;

SELECT max(IDLog) + 1 INTO ID_novo FROM log_medicoes;
INSERT INTO log_medicoes (IDLog, IDVariavel, IDCultura, NumMedicao, DataHoraMedicao, ValorMedicao, Utilizador, Data, Operacao) 
VALUES (ID_novo, IDVariavel, IDCultura, NumMedicao, DataHoraMedicao, ValorMedicao, user_id(), now(), 'S');

SELECT ID_variavel, Num_medicao, ID_cultura, Data_hora, Valor FROM medicoes;
END
```

I was given a code very similar to this one, I adapted it for my database, but I get the following error on the second line: **"RESULT" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier.**

Is this related to mySQL or is anything wrong with my code? What would be a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you intend to have some out parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `result` is supposed to be doing.  There is no `RESULT` keyword in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_medicoes (
    in_ID_variavel INTEGER,
    in_Num_medicao INTEGER,
    in_ID_cultura INTEGER,
    in_Data_hora DATE,
    in_Valor INTEGER
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ID_novo INTEGER;

    SELECT max(IDLog) + 1 INTO ID_novo FROM log_medicoes;

    INSERT INTO log_medicoes (IDLog, IDVariavel, IDCultura, NumMedicao, DataHoraMedicao, ValorMedicao, Utilizador, Data, Operacao) 
        VALUES (in_ID_novo, in_IDVariavel, in_IDCultura, in_NumMedicao, in_DataHoraMedicao, in_ValorMedicao, user_id(), now(), 'S');

    SELECT ID_variavel, Num_medicao, ID_cultura, Data_hora, Valor
    FROM medicoes;
END;
```

Having said that, you should not be calculating the id yourself.  This introduces race conditions and means that your code is not thread-safe.  You should be using an `auto_increment` column for the id.